# locationManager didUpdateLocations returns zero coordinates (0, 0)

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I am developing an app that polls the user locations constantly. On most devices, the location returned to didUpdateLocations is correct, but on some devices it is (0, 0), although everything seems to be right - permissions, delegate etc.
didFailWithError is never called either.
I have seen only a few questions like this, but didn't see a solution.
Any ideas?

```
  locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  locationManager.delegate = self;
  spotGeofences = [NSMutableArray array];
  [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
  locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
  locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
  locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeOtherNavigation;
  locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
  locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
  locationManager.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = TRUE;
```

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
      [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations {
//Here I get (0, 0) :[
}
```

Comment: Are you using simulators or real devices? If you are using simulators please check its settings. If you are using devices try reboot the device.

Comment: Thanks @DuyNguyễn. This is on real devices. Will try rebooting.

Comment: Also, do you need to use `CLActivityTypeOtherNavigation`? As it is recommended to use this type only for navigation on boat, train, or plane, not pedestrian.